# Moved tons of files without realizing it and can't undo. Please tell me there is a way to restore the previous file locations

Tags: mac, filesystems, file-transfer, file-management

I moved tons of files into a location to then back them up. I thought it was copying but instead they all moved. I undid the last few moves but that wasn't enough to restore all moves and now I have thousands of files in one location destroying hours worth of organization. Please tell me there is a way to restore the file locations. I am on a mac OS EL X Capitan

Comment: There are only 5 undo steps. After that, there's Time Machine... though TM would have backed everything up without you having to move it all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Files moved implies files deleted. In general in most operating systems files are physically NOT deleted, only pointers/links to them in the filesystem are deleted. For this reason, "Disk recovery" programs are able to easily restore files.

It is unlikely that you will be able to restore any faster than recover, but if time is not a constraint I think a use/purchase of a "disk recovery solution for Mac" will do the trick. Most paid programs have trial features where they will show you your files but not allow allow restoration unless paid.